# "Thread safety" in Redux?

Tags: redux

Let's pretend I have a long-running function working on computing my new state.

Meanwhile another action comes in and changes the state while the first one did not finish and is working on stuff.

If I am imagining things correctly there is no actions queue and the state might be resolved in some unpredictable manner.

Should I be worried about this at all?

I don't mean real threads, just a concept for the lack of better wording. Actions are asynchronous and state keys are being accessed by reference.

Comment: In your browser, you only have one thread for your javascript. Your long computation will therefore finish first then the second will start. Btw, you should avoid long computation as it will make the browser freeze (remember, you only have one thread for everything, UI and computation)

Comment: It's not real threads, just for the lack of better wording. Actions are asynchronous and state keys are being accessed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

I was concerned about the same thing so I just did some digging. It looks like two threads concurrently calling `dispatch()` (if it were possible) [could raise an exception](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/3a17aef0468e279cba048411f8f91dce07c55a7e/src/createStore.js#L180). But it shouldn't be possible and that error message points to a particular, different cause. The "actions queue" is in the browser's own event loop. That event loop runs async/interaction callbacks (from which we call `dispatch()`) one-at-a-time.

Answer (score 0):

That's the responsibility of your own action creators and your own reducers, and heavily related to how you structure your actions and reducers conceptually.  The Redux FAQ question on structuring "business logic" is very relevant here:[Redux FAQ](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#structure-business-logic.)

Thunk action creators have access to `getState`, so it's very common to have a thunk check the current state and only dispatch under certain conditions, such as this example:

```js
// An example of conditional dispatching based on state
const MAX_TODOS = 5;

function addTodosIfAllowed(todoText) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState();

        if(state.todos.length < MAX_TODOS) {
            dispatch({type : "ADD_TODO", text : todoText});
        }    
    }
}
```

Your reducer can also have sanity checks as well:

```js
function todosReducer(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "ADD_TODO": {
            if(state.todos.length >= state.maxTodos) {
                return state;
            }

            return {
                ...state,
                todos : state.todos.concat(action.newTodo)
            }
        }
        default : return state;        
    }    
}
```

Personally, I don't like to have my reducers just blindly merge in whatever data's in the action, unless it's very small (like, say, the name of the currently selected tab or something).  I prefer to have a reasonable amount of logic in my action creator to set up the action, a minimal-ish amount of data included in the action itself, and a sufficiently smart reducer to do the work based on that action.

Comment: The part of the Faq you're linking to was removed. Could you please point me to the relevant section in the updated one?

Comment: The entire FAQ is still there, including the question.  Unfortunately, the Gitbook software has a problem with bouncing back to the top of the page after it's loaded. When I wrote the FAQ, I added a plugin to fix that, but it seems the current upload of the docs is missing that.  If you go to that link and then hit Enter in your URL bar after the page is loaded, it should jump straight to the correct question.  You can also find the link to the "Business Logic" question in the Table of Contents at the top of the FAQ page.  I'll see if I can fix the page behavior later.